# What is the meaning of each parameter for *(*ocNY1) from the shell command `echo`?

Tags: zsh, glob

I could not find the proper place to look up for the parameter explanation for the below command.

```bash
echo *(*ocNY1)
```

After some tests, I discovered that `*(*oc)` prints executable files(file with `x` permission) from the current directory. And `NY1` prints the first item of such. But I cannot find the manual for such options. Where can I find the definition/manual for the parameters of such?

Where can I lookup to see the explanation for each parameters for the pattern matching?
Is this glob pattern or regex that `echo` is using?

Sometimes it is really hard to take the first step if you do not know where you are heading.

Comment: Try `man zshexpn` under the section `Glob Qualifiers` or https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*(*ocNY1)` is a zsh glob pattern - see `man zshexpn`.

`*` is a glob operator that matches any string, including the null string.

The trailing `(...)` contains glob qualifiers:

- `*` to match executable plain files
- `oc` sort by time of last inode change, youngest first
- `N` sets the `nullglob` option for the current pattern
- `Yn` expand to at most *n* filenames

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation along with the manual. I could not find the place to lookup.